# how slow is mutex synchronization than no synchronization in 2 threads

Tags: multithreading, synchronization, mutex, latency

I have two threads that need to run in different cores. When I provide no synchronization in the code, it takes only ~0.6 seconds to execute the threads in the code (for an iteration of N=100000000). When I run the same code with mutex synchronization, the thread to thread time is ~3 seconds. I am not sure if this is what it should show. Should it be this slow? or am i making a mistake in my code.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sched.h>


int x=0;
long long i;
long long count=0;
pthread_mutex_t mutex;


double getsecs(void)
{
    struct timeval tv;
    gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
    return tv.tv_sec + tv.tv_usec / 1.0e6;
}


void* changetoone(void *arg)
        { 

  pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

         for (i=0; i<10000000; i++){

            count2=i;
            while(x!=1)


            { count= count+1;
                x=1;

              //printf("%d", x);


            }
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

         }
         return NULL;

        }


void* changetozero(void *arg){
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);//we can set one or more bits here, each one representing a single CPU

 for (i=0; i<10000000; i++){
            while(x!=0)
            {count= count+1;
             x=0;


          printf("%d", x);


             }
          pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);   
        } 

        return 0;           
       } 


int main()
{


    double t1 = getsecs();

    pthread_t thread1;

    pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, changetoone, &x);

    pthread_t thread2;
    pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, changetozero, &x);    

    pthread_join(thread1, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread2, NULL);

    double t2 = getsecs();


    printf("elapsed seconds: %f, %f  uS/iteration\n", t2-t1,1000000*(t2-t1)/100000000);
   printf("%lld\n", count);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, to be honest, it really doesn't *matter* how much slower it is. Either you need synchronisation or you don't.

Not using it when it's needed is likely to result in incorrect results. Would you rather have slow code or incorrect code?

Having said that, I see that your threads lock the mutex for the entire duration of the ten-million-iteration loop. That's effectively the same as calling the two functions sequentially. If you wanted true concurrency, the lock and unlock operations would be *inside* the loop, something like (pseudo-code):

```
do 10,000,000 times:
    lock mutex
    do operation
    unlock mutex
```

But keep in mind, threading is useful only where contention is relatively *low*. If two threads need a lock for 99% of the time (as seems to be the case in your code, even *with* moving the lock within the loop), you won't see that much improvement, if any.

You *may* even see degradation since the threads are still mostly mutually exclusive, but with added mutex stuff to slow it all down.

Comment: increasing the N to 100000000 gives 26 s for mutex. I am still unsure if this is how slow it will be. My objective is to look at the times for different synchronization method.

Comment: @ZZI. That's fine but I'm not sure you've read my answer. You should try synchronisation *within* the loop to see what effect that has. But you need to keep in mind that multi-threading will not give you a lot of performance gain if the threads spend most of their time with a lock.

Comment: @ZZI - To put it another way: you need to understand what you are measuring if you want to get measurements that will be meaningful, and help you solve your actual (or hypothetical) problem.